# Custom MappedEntityDomainManager throws StackOverflowException

Tags: stack-overflow, automapper, azure-mobile-services

I created a custom MappedEntityDomainManager to map my data objects to the DTOs. For the last couple of day I'm trying to figure out in a TableController why it throws a StackOverflowException. This is the only MappedEntityDomainManager I have so far to test AutoMapper.

The data object and DTO model.

```
    public class PostDto : EntityData
    {
        public PostDto()
        {
            User = new UserDto();
            PhotoUrls = new HashSet<PostPhotoUrlDto>();    
        }

        public DateTimeOffset DatePosted { get; set; }
        public string StatusText { get; set; }
        public int TypeOfPost { get; set; }

        public UserDto User { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PostPhotoUrlDto> PhotoUrls { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post : EntityData
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset DatePosted { get; set; }
        public string StatusText { get; set; }
        public PostType TypeOfPost { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PostPhotoUrl> PhotoUrls { get; set; }
    }
```

The DomainManager.

```
public class PostDtoToPostMappedEntityDomainManager : MappedEntityDomainManager<PostDto, Post>
    {
        public PostDtoToPostMappedEntityDomainManager(DbContext context, HttpRequestMessage request, ApiServices services)
            : base(context, request, services)
        {
        }

        public PostDtoToPostMappedEntityDomainManager(DbContext context, HttpRequestMessage request, ApiServices services, bool enableSoftDelete)
            : base(context, request, services, enableSoftDelete)
        {
        }

        public override IQueryable<PostDto> Query()
        {
            return base.Query();
        }

        public override SingleResult<PostDto> Lookup(string id)
        {
            return this.LookupEntity(model => model.Id == id);
        }

        public override Task<PostDto> UpdateAsync(string id, Delta<PostDto> patch)
        {
            return base.UpdateEntityAsync(patch, id);
        }

        public override Task<bool> DeleteAsync(string id)
        {
            return base.DeleteItemAsync(id);
        }
    }
```

The mapping configurations.

```
            cfg.CreateMap<Post, PostDto>()
                .ForMember(postDto => postDto.TypeOfPost, map => map.MapFrom(post => (int) post.TypeOfPost))
                .ForMember(postDto => postDto.User, map => map.MapFrom(post => post.User))
                .ForMember(postDto => postDto.PhotoUrls, map => map.MapFrom(post => post.PhotoUrls));

            cfg.CreateMap<PostDto, Post>()
                .ForMember(post => post.TypeOfPost, map => map.MapFrom(postDto => postDto.TypeOfPost))
                .ForMember(post => post.User, map => map.MapFrom(postDto => postDto.User))
                .ForMember(post => post.PhotoUrls, map => map.MapFrom(postDto => postDto.PhotoUrls));
```

In PostController.

```
        // GET tables/Post
        public IQueryable<PostDto> GetAllPost()
        {
            return Query();
        }
```

The exception is thrown in the `PostDtoToPostMappedEntityDomainManager` `public override IQueryable<PostDto> Query()` method.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

{Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}
```

If I change the Query() method to select my new DTO manually it works fine, I just can't understand what AutoMapper needs at this point.

```
            public override IQueryable<PostDto> Query()
            {
                MobileServiceContext ctx = this.Context as MobileServiceContext;

                return ctx
                    .Posts
                    .Include(post => post.User)
                    .Include(post => post.PhotoUrls).AsNoTracking()
                    .ToArray()
                    .Select(x => new PostDto
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    DatePosted = x.DatePosted,
                    StatusText = x.StatusText,
                    TypeOfPost = (int)x.TypeOfPost,
                    User = new UserDto
                    {
                        Id = x.User.Id,
                        FirstName = x.User.FirstName
                    },
                    PhotoUrls = new List<PostPhotoUrlDto>()
                    {
                        new PostPhotoUrlDto() { Url = "AURL" }
                    }
                }).AsQueryable();
            }
```

**EDIT**

After `whitelatino` answer I started commenting navigation properties and trying things ending with the solution.
The problem was deeper in the relationships with a circular dependency in District => Clubs => District, see below the setup.

```
        public class PostEntityTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Post>
        {
            public PostEntityTypeConfiguration()
            {
                // Properties
                HasRequired(post => post.User);
                HasMany(post => post.PhotoUrls).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ph => ph.PostId);
            }
        }

        public class UserEntityTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
        {
            public UserEntityTypeConfiguration()
            {
                // Properties
                HasOptional(user => user.Club);
                HasMany(user => user.Posts).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(post => post.UserId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            }
        }

    public class ClubEntityTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Club>
    {
        public ClubEntityTypeConfiguration()
        {
            // Properties
            HasMany(club => club.Members).WithOptional(user => user.Club).HasForeignKey(user => user.ClubId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            HasRequired(club => club.ClubDistrict); // Left this as is
        }
    }

    public class DistrictEntityTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<District>
    {
        public DistrictEntityTypeConfiguration()
        {
            // Properties
            // HasMany(district => district.Clubs).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(club => club.DistrictId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false); // I had to comment this and remove the navigation list property "Clubs" from the District data object.
        }
    }
```

No EntityTypeConfiguration for the PostPhotoUrlDto.

```
    public class PostPhotoUrl : EntityData
    {
        public string PostId { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }

        public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    }

    public class Club : EntityData
    {
        // Properties

        public virtual District ClubDistrict { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<User> Members { get; set; } 
    }

    public class User : EntityData
    {
        // Properties

        public virtual Club Club { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

        public User()
        {
            Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
        }
    }

    public class District : EntityData
    {
        // Properties

        // public virtual ICollection<Club> Clubs { get; set; } // Had to comment this, it is causing a stackoverflow because of the circular dependency
    }
```

I don't really need to access the navigation list property so this is solving my problem. Also I see that the database schema relationship is created appropriately.

It is also remarkable that I had to change the public `IQueryable<PostDto> GetAllPost()` method to `IEnumerable<PostDto> GetAllPost()` to properly receive a JSON with navigation properties included. 
See below the resulting final method.

```
        // GET tables/Post
        public async Task<IEnumerable<PostDto>> GetAllPost()
        {
            return await Query().ToListAsync();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stackoverflowexception is caused by a recursive loop, that is two navigation properties referring to each other. I had the same problem in my many to many relationseship. I fixed it by removing the navigation property (list) on one of the entities and instead did the many to many mapping with:

`modelBuilder.Entity<Event>().HasMany(m => m.HostList).WithMany();`

Comment: It was a problem with a deeper navigation properties relationship. I have updated my question with all the details for others that might face the same issue in a little bit more complicated schema than basic.